# Updating the UI when using a serial queue

Tags: iphone, multithreading, ipad, ios

I am using a serial queue to do a background thread (block) for video processing. I want to update a UI component (specifically a progress bar). I've found that while I can interact with the UI, my progress bar is not updating with calls to setProgress (called from the block), until the thread has finished.

```
dispatch_queue_t dispatch_queue = dispatch_queue_create("somequeue", NULL);

    [somebody doSomethingOnQueue:dispatch_queue usingBlock:^{

        progressBar.progress = someFloat; //does not update

    }];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should update the UI on the main dispatch queue:

```
[somebody doSomethingOnQueue:dispatch_queue usingBlock:^{
    …
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        progressBar.progress = someFloat;
    });
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm using the [videoWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:dispatch_queue usingBlock API, which requests a serial queue.